# Who is responsible for search engine indexing? (GDPR)

Tags: gdpr, european-union

I am currently trying to wrap my head around the GDPR by analysing mastodon.online. While going through their privacy policy and their privacy preferences of my Mastodon, I discovered the following preference setting which is enabled by default:

[image: Screenshot]

As far as I understand [Article 25 of the GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-25-gdpr/), checkboxes and consent-based preferences shall choose privacy by default. Apparently, this is not the case for this setting.

The question: Is this part of the data controller's responsibility, since it can detect and hence block search engines? If so, is Google considered a data processor or a separate data controller, which obtains the publicly available data?

Comment: If you're running your own instance of Mastodon on your own server, you're the data controller.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/88918/what-are-the-possible-copyright-and-other-legal-issues-faced-by-an-individual-in

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. Currently, I try to evaluate whether this is a specific violation of the GDPR. Is this a direct violation of the privacy-by-default article of the GDPR? Or is it viewed from the perspective of Google, since they do the search indexing?

Comment: It is definitely the right direction, thanks!. Unfortunately, they do not refer explicitly to the GDPR but rather on intuition in my opinion. But the outcome is a quite interesting perspective. I suppose that the website who publishes the data is responsible for restricting the access to the data, which also includes the denial of search engine access. But I want an explicit answer to that question. Currently, I only have vague ideas of how to frame this.

Comment: @lukasl-dev A couple months after I wrote that answer, the CJEU decided in case C-507/17 that Google doesn't have to delete personal data from its search index, but may have to hide it from European searchers – some of Googles processing activities are subject to the GDPR, some are not. In any case, both Google and a Mastodon admin would be separate data controllers, both responsible for their own compliance. I agree with you that the noindex-option should probably be enabled by default.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you, that answers my question! Do you want to write an answer, so I can accept it?